# Non-manual creation of appliance image (OVA)

Tags: virtualization, ovf

I want to distribute base OS (Ubuntu 14.04) and my app+dependencies as an appliance in OVA format. So that once users deploy it in their virtualization systems, they have an operational system

I can do this manually by manually creation VM, installing app+dependencies and exporting it in OVA format from hypervisor (e.g. vBox)

Is there a non-manual automated way for doing the same? Bcoz I want to do the build from my Continuous Integration env. VMware Studio looks like an option but there hasn't been any updates to that since 2012

Answer (score 1):

The 2 tools I've used are packer (https://www.packer.io) and veewee (https://github.com/jedi4ever/veewee). They both allow you to easily build virtual appliances like you are describing.